# Clear Input Fields on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a input field where in user enters data. There are 2 buttons next to it upon click any one of them or both the input fields get reset. Now since these buttons and field is not inside a form I can't go for a  instead how can i clear it with JQuery. The point is, now I have displayed only 2 buttons, the JQuery must also work if there where more buttons..Fiddle link below and the code i tried

```
$('button').each(function(){
   $('button').click(function(){
      find('input[type="text"]').val() = "0";
   });
});
```

[Fiddle link] http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/1s22gcL5/

Thanks to all for help.

Comment: The val() method gets or sets the value of the "selected" elements, to set it , add the new value as a parameter ,  so to reset the field call: val("")

Comment: Hey Guys there is a bug i just figuered or may be I am wrong,but just to get cleared. On the same fiddle when you console log you will find one button click is equal to two buttons getting clicked.  To prove my point here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/1s22gcL5/12/. Open up your consoles and see. Just clicking one button, the console shows 2 clicked...how can it be cleared..

Comment: <input type="reset" />

Comment: no no punitha.. i dont want to use <input type="reset" /> as I am not using forms here...i want to do it via JQuery

Comment: @VineetGNair..just remove $('button').each(function(){ line and see..

Comment: Oh yes! that did it @ Exception

Comment: @Exception i did accept the answer 45 mins ago..oh sorry...i din know about the tick mark.. i am new to stack...done now..

Comment: @VineetGNair...Cheers...Great..!!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $('input[type="text"]').val(0);
});
```

If you want to just reset field then :

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $('input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No need of saying each, just say `.click` it will apply for every button

```
$('button').click(function(){
      $('input[type="text"]').val(0);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1s22gcL5/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of javascript variable defining to jQuery.function = 0, you should just reset the value to clear the contents of the input field with `.val('');`

```
$('button').each(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').val('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This clean text field:

```
 $('button').click(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').val("");
    });
```

This change value to 0:

```
 $('button').click(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').val(0);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $('input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to clear your input field on button click.

```
$('button').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').val('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here'e the code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   $('input[type="text"]').val('0');
});
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="reset" value="button 2" />
```