# Reset Bootstrap Dropdown values to default on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I would like to reset all filter dropdown values to default values with a press on a button. As you might see in my example code, reseting it this way only changes all values to "Filter". I need it to reset it to "Car brand" and "model".

This is my code:

```js
// set....
$(".dropdown-menu li a").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".dropdown").find('.btn').text($(this).text() + ' ');
});


// reset.....
$('.resetdropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    $(".dropdown .btn").text('Filter');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="search-filter-content">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Car brand</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">Audi</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">BMW</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">Citroen</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="search-filter-content">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Model</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">option1</a></li>
           <li><a class="dropdown-item">option2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">option3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-filter resetdropdown">Reset value</button>
```

Comment: I'm reluctant to write a function for you as this is pretty basic stuff and is _well_ covered on SO and elsewhere. You have a click handler for your list items. Just do similar for your reset button. At least take a crack at it, which is the expectation around these parts, then we can discuss.

Comment: I'd also advise you to get away from jQuery. It's not necessary with Bootstrap 5, and it's [rarely necessary in general](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) with modern browsers. It's a crutch to your learning and a load on your users.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502206/clear-input-fields-on-button-click

Answer (score 0):

First:  when you add an event listener in jQuery I would suggest to use  [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

In order to solve your issue it's enough you add a click event handler for the "Reset vaue" button and inside use the method [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/).

```js
// set....
$(".dropdown-menu li a").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".dropdown").find('.btn').text($(this).text() + ' ');
});


// reset.....
$('.resetdropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    $(".dropdown .btn").text('Filter');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



<div class="search-filter-content">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Filter</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Audi</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">BMW</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Citroen</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Ford</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Marcedez-Benz</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Opel</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Peugeot</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Renault</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Škoda</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item">Wolksvagen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-filter resetdropdown">
    Reset value</button>
```

Comment: $('.resetdropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    $(".dropdown .btn").text('Filter');
})   this doesn't reset it just sets all dropdown's to "filter", i want it to reset to default values.

Comment: Let's say instead of  <a>Filter</a> I have <a>Car brand</a>, for other dropdowns some other values. I don't want it all to reset to "Filter", I want it to go back to default's for example "Car brand"... Hope this explains it.

Comment: Did you run the snippet? If it works, like you can experience by yourself, it's a matter of your code.... In this case add more info. Thanks

Comment: I edited my code with your JS, maybe that will explain it better. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @MackBack  You changed your code adding a new dropdown. Moreover, you use twice the same ID (**dropdownMenuLink**): this is forbidden. Please, clarify what are you looking for and only after I or another guy can help you. My code works but because now you have two drodowns it reset both. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for noticing, was copy pasting. So on press of a button both dropdowns should go back to default values, first one being "Car brand", and second one being "Model"

Comment: I think I just figured it out, ill keep you posted :)